# asking password when clone or push - docker gitlab

Tags: git, docker, ssh, passwords, gitlab

I just installed the latest version of gitlab with docker (https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) and added my ssh key, but it still asks for a password when I try pushing to this docker gitlab.

> desktop system: window10,osx
>
> server system : centos 7
>
> docker git (lastest version): docker pull gitlab/gitlab-ce

Here is the `ssh -vt` output:

```
$ ssh -vt git@23.234.53.236
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 23.234.53.236 [23.234.53.236] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 23.234.53.236:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VgBduYKrMafvYg27PfLCXZmiA0vCAnz8obliVveAX+Y
debug1: Host '23.234.53.236' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@23.234.53.236's password:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check that:

- you did add the [content of the *public* key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#locating-an-existing-ssh-key-pair) (`/c/Users/Nathan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to your GitLab SSH setting account page (in one line)
- (if you can access the server) that `23.234.53.236:~/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` does include that public key as well.

Comment: @Nathan Do you have access to the ~git home directory on that server?

Comment: 1.i did add to gitlab    2.is on the inside docker path:/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh

Comment: @Nathan Maybe https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/common_installation_problems/README.html#git-user-does-not-have-ssh-access then?

Comment: @Nathan Do you know if the authorized_keys file is persisted (ie part of a Docker volume) between sessions? Or does it disappear when you restart the GitLab container?

Comment: yes,i had config for the persisted ,after restart i still have authorized_keys

Comment: @Nathan does that authorized_keys file (in the container) still include your public key?

Comment: thank you Vonc,the problem is Gitlab not adding SSH keys to authorized_keys,thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

this is problem with "Gitlab not adding SSH keys to authorized_keys since upgrade"
here is the solution:

`root@int-gitlab-01:~  # gitlab-rake gitlab:shell:setup
This will rebuild an authorized_keys file.
You will lose any data stored in authorized_keys file.
Do you want to continue (yes/no)? yes`

..........................................................................

`root@int-gitlab-01:~  # su - git
Last login: Mon Jul 10 09:24:30 AEST 2017 on pts/0
git@int-gitlab-01:~  # ls -la .ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 git git 43286 Jul 10 13:36 .ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Interesting feedback. +1. More precise than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same symptoms on a more recent version, with a different cause:

The latest version successfully updates `authorized_keys`, and you can confirm that it's all set up correctly by running

```
ssh -p [port_here] git@[ip_or_host_here]
```

(which should connect without asking for a password but then immediately kick you out, since the git user has no shell access. If it asks for a password you will need to check that you have installed your public key correctly on the GitLab UI and that you have set up your private key on your local machine)

If that command works, but cloning asks for a password, here's a possible fix which worked for me:

1. You *must* be connecting to the correct host. Using an IP won't work. For example, if you have the default `gitlab.example.com`, then add `gitlab.example.com 127.0.0.1` to your local hosts file.
2. If you're trying to clone using any port except 22, you will need to patch a file:

   1. On the gitlab box, open `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` (e.g. in `vi`)
   2. Search for `ssh_port`. You should find a line like this:

      `# gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 22`
   3. Uncomment the line and change 22 to the port you're using
   4. Save this file, and maybe restart the docker image (I restarted it, though I'm not sure if that was required)

If either the host or the port does not match, it won't check your SSH key and will fall-back to password security. I'm sure there are many other things which could be wrong, but for me it was this combination of 2 issues which don't seem to have been explained elsewhere.

You can find some more discussion along with other possible causes [on this GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4110) and [this docker-gitlab issue](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/issues/34).